# How to bind live data with event base calendar in asp.net core 6.0 with jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I have been trying to solve this problem for 2 days but i didnt get any success.
I got problem with this code here,

```
events.push({
                                    title: v.Subject,
                                    description: v.Description,
                                    start: moment(v.Start),
                                    end: v.End != null ? moment(v.End) : null,
                                    color: v.ThemeColor,
                                    allDay: v.IsFullDay
                              
                                 
                              });
```

For adding an event base calendar I follow this link.
http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2017/06/event-calendar-in-aspnet-mvc.html

And I have added exactly the same code which is existing on the above blog.
The calendar is displayed but live data is not attached.

Even though I didn't get any error in jquery, I have found that when data is didn't pushed inside for loop. I have also attached a snapshot of where I got stuck.
pl, anyone can help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Hi @Geeta Chauhan , have your problem been solved ?